# Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I used this code

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
        [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

and I'm getting error "Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments"

Comment: Slightly different question, but essentially the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499815/nsfontattributedstring-worked-before-xcode-6-1/26500637#26500637

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UIFont(name:size:)` is now a *failable initializer* -- it will return `nil` if it can't find that font and crash your app if you unwrap the return value. Use this code to safely get the font and use it:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = 
            [NSFontAttributeName: font, 
             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
        [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()!]
```

or this one

```
if let font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20.0) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes  = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: font]
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `!` after `UIcolor.whiteColor()` as it doesn't return an optional. In fact, using it will give you a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to build up a dictionary before setting `titleTextAttributes`. This just avoids you the else(s), which would be more beneficial in cases where you wanted to set further parameters also using failable initialisers. Eg:

```
var attributes : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20) {
    attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
}

if let someData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "dataPath") {
    attributes["imageData"] = someData
}

self.myObject.attributes = attributes
```